# Как проследить включение и выключение компьютеров в домене (в сети)?

Tags: администрирование, windows-server-2008-r2

Стоит задача проследить: во сколько включается и выключается компьютер пользователя, находящийся в домене.

Контроллер домена стоит на Windows Server 2008 r2.

Может быть есть какие-то стандартные средства в той же Active Directory или какие-то сторонние решения?

Comment: Ну вообще - это должно быть в журналах винды. Если хочется чего-то кастомного, то автозагрузка, curl\samba в rw к твоим услугам.

Comment: @don Rumata, на винде хотелось бы эту информацию как-то подтягивать и смотреть с сервера. Интересует момент не продолжительности работы компьютера, а время во сколько сотрудник его включает и затем выключает собственноручно

Comment: В `zabbix` смотрел? Оверхэд, но потом если захочешь смотреть ещё чё-нить, то оно уже там будет.